# How to change the breaks in date axis + rotate them 90 degrees

Tags: r, plot, time-series

How can I possibly change the breaks in the `timeSeries::plot` function + make them vertical?

My attempt was:

```
library(timeSeries)
test_xlab = as.Date(paste0("2000-01-",10:16))

timeSeries::plot(as.timeSeries(seq(10,70,10), 
                                charvec = test_xlab),
                  axes = F);box()

axis.Date(side = 1,
          x = test_xlab[c(1,2,7)], 
          at = test_xlab[c(1,2,7)], 
          format = "%a", las = 2)
```

[image]

The result I was aiming with the code above was to be able to only show 3 of the 7 days of the week, on the x axis label and show them vertically.

Right now, I'm able to format it in a way so that all the days of the week are displayed, if the function is used as :

```
timeSeries::plot(as.timeSeries(seq(10,70,10), charvec = test_xlab), format = "%a", axes = T)
```

The plot generated is the following,

[image]

The plot has the days of the week in the Portuguese abbreviation, so the attempted one would have instead of `Seg,Ter, Qua, ..., Dom` - > `Seg,Ter, Dom` displayed.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired result here?

Comment: @MrFlick, added this and more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `axis.timeDate` with `las=2` like this:

```
library(timeSeries)

tt <- timeSeries(seq(10,70,10), as.Date("2000-01-10") + 0:6)

plot(tt, axes = FALSE)
box()
ok <- as.numeric(format(time(tt), "%w")) %in% 0:2
axis.timeDate(1, at = time(tt)[ok], format = "%a", las = 2)
```

[image: screenshot]